# Как отфильтровать данные в таблицы при нажатии на ячейку коллекции?

Tags: swift, filter, tableview, uicollectionview

У меня есть горизонтальная коллекция и таблица с данными, как при нажатии на ячейку коллекции менять данные в таблице?

Результат, который я хочу получить, на скриншотах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу фильтровать таблицу в соотвествии с выбранной ячейкой коллекции